# MySQL column category and position SELECT with limit 4. When category only has 3 records, select one from other category with the missing position?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two columns category and position.

```
Category     |  Position
-------------|----------
A            |  0
A            |  1
A            |  2
A            |  3
B            |  0
B            |  1
B            |  2
B            |  3
```

In my Query I select `where category = B, limit 4`. 
If category B only has 3 records I want the A record of the missing position.

How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to reframe the problem. If a given position for B is missing then use the A record. This will only work for if this statement *If category B only has 3 records*  was just a way to detect a missing position.

Then you just need to Join the A Records to the B Records and then do a Coalesce on the columns. This means that if a given position is missing for then it will use the A record.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(B_Rec.Category, A_Rec.Category) Category,
    COALESCE(B_Rec.Position , A_Rec.Position ) Position 

FROM 
    tabl A_Recs
    LEFT JOIN B_Rec
    ON A_recs.Position = B_recs.Position 
       AND a_Rec.Category = 'A' 
       AND b_Rec.Category = 'B'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from tbl
order by Category desc
limit 4
```

Comment: this isn't solving the problem, yet. Yes that is the query. But sometimes I need to select A and sometimes B or in the future C. When record B | 2 is missing I need record A | 2 to replace the missing B

Comment: i can propose salvation with union all to setup sequence of Category but its bulk and inefficient